# Razor.launch fails to launch (Razor 9DOF)

Tags: ros, roslaunch, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to test the driver package for Razor IMU 9DOF (Degree of freedom) sensors board based from this site: http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof .  I have installed Arduino and confirmed that it is working, as well as the python visual package.  I installed wine v1.4 to get the python visual package working.  After downloading and "rosmake"-ing the razor git repository without errors and running the command "roslaunch razor_imu_9dof razor.launch", i get the following error:

viki@ROS:/home/paralax2$ roslaunch razor_imu_9dof razor.launch
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid  tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1].

Param xml is < param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>

Are there any prerequisites that I may be unaware of?  Why are the scripts unable to configure logging?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172891/razor.launch-fails-to-launch-(razor-9dof)/) by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the answer to this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/57482/cant-make-razor_imu_9dof/

(Sorry, I didn't see how to link the way others do)

---

Originally posted by [Tim Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/6187/tim-murphy/) with karma: 31 on 2014-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0